# Teradata join statement syntax

Tags: sql, syntax, teradata

I have been given following sql, which seems to have issue while importing through apache calcite.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.abc, t.desc, m.qprs, m.mpn,
  m.ohug, p.tre, p.status
  FROM (table_a m table_b p 
          ON m.mat = p.mat)
          INNER JOIN table_c t ON t.mat = m.mat
  WHERE t.lang = 'E' AND p.plant LIKE '110%'
  ORDER BY p.plant desc;
```

Can someone with detailed knowledge of Teradata confirm, if this syntax is right?

If not, what could be right syntax?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `Teradata`. If your query does not work, debug it first, see what's the issue, then update your post here to reflect that specific issue. And no, syntax is not correct after a simple check. `ON` should only appear in `JOIN` statements, not in `FROM` table aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax is not correct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.abc, t.desc, m.qprs, m.mpn, m.ohug, p.tre, p.status
FROM table_a m INNER JOIN
---------------^ missing keyword
     table_b p 
     ON m.mat = p.mat INNER JOIN
     table_c t
     ON t.mat = m.mat
WHERE t.lang = 'E' AND p.plant LIKE '110%'
ORDER BY p.plant desc;
```

The parentheses are not needed, although they should be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Gordons answer , The keyword desc is a reserved keyword. Better use [] around this to avoid error.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.abc, t.[desc], m.qprs, m.mpn, m.ohug, p.tre, p.status FROM table_a m INNER JOIN
 table_b p 
 ON m.mat = p.mat INNER JOIN
 table_c t
 ON t.mat = m.mat WHERE t.lang = 'E' AND p.plant LIKE '110%' ORDER BY p.plant desc;
```

Comment: `[]` is T-SQL specific syntax, Teradata supports Standard SQL `"desc"`